# GeocoderAutoCompleteView not find in Mapbox Services

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm trying using the [MapBox Services](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/) for suggest places near of user through GeoCoding and AutoComplete :

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

But some classes Like as GeocoderAutoCompleteView don't include in this package and I don't can import the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapbox Android Services is split up into different modules so that your app only needs to include the components it needs. In particular, the [`GeocoderAutoCompleteView`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/libandroid-ui/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/ui/geocoder/GeocoderAutoCompleteView.java) is in the `mapbox-android-ui` package.